# Calculate totals by weighted values

Tags: statistics, arithmetic

I hope to be able to get some assistance here, I tried reading through some of the posts, however, they are far above my math abilities..so I apologize if this is a re-post or this is a basic question for this forum.

What i'm trying to do is calculate the costs of different services based on a weighting and quantity.

for example given a list of servies:
number of calls logged = 1000

total cost = £3000

service 1 = 400 calls,  weight = 0.5

service 2 = 200 calls, weight = 0.2

service 3 = 300 calls, weight = 0.2

service 4 = 100 calls,  weight = 0.1

given the data a call from service 1 is 5x more valuable then service 4,

my question is is there a formula that will based on the total cost will calculate the amount that each service consumes of the total or better yet what a single call of each service would cost.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format numbers and math expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total weight of all calls is
$$400\cdot 0.5+200\cdot 0.2+300\cdot 0.2+100\cdot0.1=310\ ,$$
so that a weight unit  costs £$\>{3000\over 310}$=£ $9.6774$. It follows that, e.g., a call at service 1 costs $£\>0.5\cdot9.6774=£\ 4.839$.